# Intellij/Android Studio Find/Replace a multiline view in xml layout (Android)

Tags: replace, android-studio, intellij-idea

I have to replace this

```
<fr.castorflex.android.smoothprogressbar.SmoothProgressBar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:spb_color="#FF0000"
        app:spb_mirror_mode="false"
        app:spb_progressiveStart_activated="true"
        app:spb_progressiveStart_speed="1.5"
        app:spb_progressiveStop_speed="3.4"
        app:spb_reversed="false"
        app:spb_sections_count="4"
        app:spb_speed="2.0"
        app:spb_stroke_separator_length="4dp"
        app:spb_stroke_width="4dp" />
```

by this

```
<fr.castorflex.android.smoothprogressbar.SmoothProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        style="@style/GNowProgressBar"
        android:indeterminate="true"/>
```

thoroughout my entire project using Intellij/Android Studio's Find/Replace.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 6):

(For MAC and similarly for Windows)

Click on Edit (Top Left of your Intellij/Android Studio window)
Hover your cursor to "Find"
Then select "Replace Structurally"
Now the find/replace structurally window will open. Towards the bottom side of the window, uncheck all the boxes(Otherwise it might not identify the snippet through out the project).

Comment: Thanks for `Replace Structurally`. +1.